# JavaScript: instance of Stefanov's Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I followed Stefanov's rather simple Module Pattern. Everything worked out fine till there was a huge change in design: I have to produce multiple instances of my Module.
Here is some short sample code which shows how this pattern looks like:

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};

MYAPP = (function(){

    // private properties
    var connector = "connector.php",

        my_list = [], 
        current_item = {},
        beforeRender = false;

    // private methods
    _addCurrentItem = function(amount){
    },

    // public methods
    add = function(amount){
        amount += 5;
        _addCurrentItem(amount);
    }

    // public API
    return {
        add: add
    };

}());
```

Everything was fine when just using one instance of `MYAPP`. but now I need more instances and found out that i can't instantiate my module this way. `var my_instance = new MYAPP;` doesn't work because there is no constructor.

what is the fastest and best way to make my module pattern instantiable?

thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Return a function that returns what is now your module. Or return a constructor.

Comment: Can you use actual modules?

Comment: @NickTomlin can you give me an example please?

Comment: @ssube what do you mean by an "actual module"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- Remove self-invoke
- Save to a different variable (like `App`)
- Instantiate separately

Like so:

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};

var App = function(){

    // private properties
    var connector = "connector.php",

        my_list = [], 
        current_item = {},
        beforeRender = false;

    // private methods
    _addCurrentItem = function(amount){
    },

    // public methods
    add = function(amount){
        amount += 5;
        _addCurrentItem(amount);
    }

    // public API
    return {
        add: add
    };

};

MYAPP = new App();
MYOTHERAPP = new App();
```

Comment: thanks, i am taking a look into it right now; what about private variables/methods? does the removal of the self-invocation change anything in terms of privacy at all?

Comment: Nope. As an aside, [this is also really good reading on Javascript patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). Particularly, [Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Comment: ok, thanks! I have Stefanov's book - and I don't really understand the more complicated implementations of the module pattern, when the simpler ones seem to be able to do everything.

Comment: They're very similar, in fact. You'll likely notice that most of these patterns look remarkably similar.

Comment: I think the similarity confuses me the most. And being not instantiable is a big downside for me which makes the self-invoked version useless most of the times. is this version meant to be used like a static class?

Comment: awesome answer by the way! just tested everything and it seems to work perfectly. I got quite desperate with my project but more or less just removing the self-invocation made everything work out!

Answer (score 0):

return {
    init: function () {}}

the above code effectively instantiate the Module.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.